# using loops and arrays to insert characters

Tags: java

I have to write a program that takes an array of strings(`private String[] strs = {"hello" , "xxaayybbzz" , "aabbaaccdef" , "jiladdsqss" , "g" , "allstars"};`) and use loops to put an * in between letters that repeat, so "hello" would output as `"hel*lo"`. I have to use a public String `stars()` method, and create a callStars method that calls on `stars()` and passes in the array.

I wish I had more to contribute, but I am just stuck.

```
package l6c13pairstar;

public class PairStar { private String[] strs = {"hello" , "xxaayybbzz" , "aabbaaccdef" , "jiladdsqss" , "g" , "allstars"};

    public void callStars(String stars)
    {    
    }

    public String stars(String str)
    {
       if (str.length() > 0) 
       {

                for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); ++i) 
                {

                 }

        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursion program using array of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762344/recursion-program-using-array-of-strings)

Comment: Yeah. I've never used this site before so I didn't know how to format the question, so I made a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is really about a loop, you may use a `StringBuilder`, and append the `*` as needed :

```
public String stars(String str) {

    String result;

    if (str.length() > 0) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        char lastChar = (char) -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {

            char currentChar = str.charAt(i);

            // duplicate character, we append '*'
            if (lastChar == currentChar) {

                builder.append('*');
            }

            lastChar = currentChar;
            // append the current read character
            builder.append(currentChar);
        }

        result = builder.toString();

    } else {
        // return the source String
        result = str;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then you may call it with the content of your array, like :

```
public void callStars()
    { 
       for(String str : strs){
        System.out.println(stars(str));
       }
    }
```

And your main method could simply look like :

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

   PairStar pairStar = new PairStar();
   pairStar.callStars();
}
```

**EDIT** : Since you haven't learned `StringBuilder` yet, I replaced it with a plain `String` :

```
public String stars(String str) {

    String result;
    if (str.length() > 0) {

        String builder = "";
        char lastChar = (char) -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {

            char currentChar = str.charAt(i);

            // duplicate character, we append '*'
            if (lastChar == currentChar) {

                builder = builder + '*';
            }

            lastChar = currentChar;
            // append the current read character
            builder = builder + currentChar;
        }

        result = builder;

    } else {
        // return the source String
        result = str;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: We haven't learned StringBuilder in class yet, so I was hesitant to use it, but I guess there's no choice.

Comment: @B. Fann : I edited to use a simple `String` instead .

Comment: IT's making sense, but where does the     for(String str : strs){
    System.out.println(stars(str));
   } fit in?

Comment: @B. Fann : I added a `callStars` method using the array from `PairStar`, along with a sample `main` method .

Comment: Hey man, I appreciate all the help and it's ALMOST working... but the first letters of all of the strings are cut off... (ie. "Hello" = "el*lo")

Comment: You are right, the loops should start at `i = 0` , I edited to reflect this .